# Is it possible to read iPhone or Android display data through the audio jack?

Tags: android, ios

I'm not very well versed in the iPhone and Android API, so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

As I understand it, Square's card reader works by converting the magnetic information on the card stripe into an audio tone that its software can then process. [1](http://www.quora.com/How-does-Squares-hardware-work)

In a similar way, is there a way to somehow read what exactly is being displayed on the device screen simply through a small device inserted into the audio jack on that device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you wish to achieve. You can indeed make an app that would output a [representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation) (perhaps [audio frequency-shift keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_frequency-shift_keying#Audio_FSK)?) of the screen's contents to the iPhone's audio jack.

The iPhone (and other iOS-based devices) use [TRRS connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector) for bi-directional audio (and hence arbitrary modulated data) communication and there are well-supported publicly-documented APIs for using these interfaces.

That said, if you're writing your own app: why would you want to output the contents of the screen? If you are developing the app in question, why not transmit the salient data in a more effective manner? Which leads me to my next assumption:

You want to read what's being displayed on the device's screen at *any* time, not just when an app of your creation is open. In this case, the answer is that it is not possible, with the possible exception of a jailbroken solution. That said, I can't imagine a jailbroken solution being useful much longer on account of iOS 5 introduced "display mirroring" by means of AirPlay.

---

On Android, I have no idea. :-)

Comment: Can you please help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026002/read-data-through-iphone-audio-jack

Answer (score 0):

No. The screen is not connected to the audio jack.

Comment: So the *only* information I can read from the audio jack is auditory information (music, sound)?

Comment: Only information you can read from audio jack is the information sent by the device connected to the audio jack.

It's the responsability of the connected device to convert some informations (magnetic card, voltage level meter, ...) with an electronical interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make an app to take a screenshot and then encode that photo as music to play it.

It won't sound good though :)

Answer (score -1):

For this kind of task, there is built in camera

Comment: That is obvious, but that was not what I was asking about.